# Boolean attribute or new table (Django + PostgreSQL)

Tags: django, database, postgresql

Situation: I have a Books set. Book can be one of the types: "Test", "Premium" and "Common". Data proportional: 2%, 15%, 83%. Amount query per time unit (in percent): 40%, 20%, 40%

I see some ways for resolve it in database:

1. Boolean: is_test, is_premium. If we need only "Tests" book: `Book.objects.filter(is_test=True)`. It is can be a proxy model, for example. Analogy for premium books;
2. Separate Tables: books_test, books_premium, books_common.
3. Choice field: string in `['Test', 'Premium', 'Common']`;
4. Combine 1 and 2: books_test table and books table with 'is_premium' attribute.

And we need optimally querying this data! All three Book variants need in one page. Exist queryset combinations: only tests, only common, common + premium, only premium.

- If we use 1,3 variant: 1 endpoint with specific filter;
- If we use 2 variant: one of the tree endpoints without filters (frontend should know what kind endpoint use). Or we can create one endpoint with some conditions and check by backend. Anyway: need extend logic;

Which way is more correct and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to mix different types on one page, separate models/tables would complicate things for no good reason. The same goes for mapping more than two exclusive states to a combination of boolean fields.

This leaves you with a choice field or a separate `BookType` model containing the choices.

Comment: What about variant #4? He exclude premium+common join. And exist the opinion what getting "Test" books from common table - excessively difficult. May be books_test separated table have a chance for a life?

Comment: #3 and #4 are conceptually different: In #3 you have 3 mutually exclusive states; in #4 you have two sets of mutually exclusive states: 1) test/common and 2) premium/non-premium that can be combined in 4 ways. Which one of the two different concepts you choose depends on the reality that you want to model. With #4, you could use two booleans (if you are quite sure that there won't be further types).

Comment: My model should complete this goals: "...Exist queryset combinations: only tests, only common, common + premium, only premium..." - and each of four ways can give me goal-result. I need to understand, what better: one table, or one of the variants with separated tables

Comment: I almost understood what you mean =)

Comment: Me too :). The main question is not what combinations you want in your querysets, but what combinations of these attributes are valid *in a single book*.

Comment: Only 1 state for a book. Without combinations.

Comment: Then #3 seems perfect; definitely no separate tables.

Comment: Why #3? May be 2 boolean fields in #1? I think filter by boolean field is more easy (in database)